# Clearing the Sqlite database and then using cat command shows the deleted data

Tags: sqlite, qnx

I am using squlite database to store the phone book data in my project. During some operation i am flushing or clearing the database .But when i run the cat command, it still shows the deleted data.
I had exported the database after the operation to double check and it shows no data but when the cat command is used, it shows the deleted data.
Could anyone please let me know if there is any work around for this so that cat command also shows nothing?

Comment: What is 'the cat command'? There is none in SQLite.

Comment: @Tichodrama I am actually using QNX momentics IDE where when i wanted to check the contents of the btpbk shows deleted data.

Comment: sqlite does not overwrite data when you delete it

Answer (score 1):

By default, deleted data is not overwritten.
(Freed pages are reused for new data inserted later.)

If you want to overwrite deleted content with zeros, use [PRAGMA secure_delete;](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_secure_delete).